Correlation grouping by multiple variables
all. I've trying to perform correlation, grouping by two variables, as ideally the data would be present in the same data and be of the same type.
Let's say I have the following dataframe:
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
  type = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
  date = as.Date(c('2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-01','2023-02-01', '2023-03-01','2023-04-01',
                 '2023-01-01', '2023-02-01'), format = '%Y-%m-%d'),
  revenue = c(1,3,2,4,5,1,2,3)
)


Is there any way to get the correlation between the ID's and revenues grouping by Type/Date?
I tried to use pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = revenue and then use summarise, but it didn't work out.
Ideally, I would have some table with every ID in the row and column, and the correlation coefficient in the cell.

For type=1 and date=2023-01-01 you want the correlation between c(1, 1, 1) and c(1, 3, 2)?

Oh I see, there's an error in your code: you probably want as.Date(c(...), format = 'foo')

I think that
cfun <- function(x, y) {
    if (length(x) <= 2) return(NA_real_)
    cor.test(x, y)$stat
}

(df
    |> group_by(type, date)
    |> summarise(cor = cfun(ID, revenue))
)

will probably do what you want; in your example it returns all NA values because you have at most two observations per group, which is not enough to compute a correlation.
I'd also advise that you think hard about whether it makes sense to compute a correlation between ID, which seems to be a categorical predictor with labels whose order doesn't matter, and a continuous revenue variable ...  there might be a more sensible summary statistic, like the fraction of total variance in revenue that's explained by among-ID variation ...
